# Google Apps Script - Document and Announcements

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-script, google-sites

So here's the scenario I've been trying to solve. A user comes to our site, uploads a file, that file is sent to a google docs collection and generates a link to that doc which is emailed to an administrator. I have an announcements page that I would like to update automatically via this script to include the link to the doc in the announcement... here's the code

```
function newAnnouncement(parameter){
    var site = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("https://sites.google.com/a/westcongps.com/dhcorpintranettestsite/company-blog");
    site.createAnnouncement("this is the title", '<a href="' + parameter + '">LINK TEXT</a>');
}

function doGet(e) {  
    // creates the ui application  
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    // set's up the application user interface.
    var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
    var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
    form.add(formContent);  
    var fileUp = app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile');
    var submit = app.createSubmitButton('Submit');  
    formContent.add(fileUp);
    formContent.add(submit);
    app.add(form);
    submit.setPixelSize(75, 20);

    return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
    // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
    var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
    var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
    //var to store the folder the file will be uploaded to
    var folder = DocsList.getFolder("collection");
    //adds the document to the folder ^^^  
    doc.addToFolder(folder);
    var emailAddress = "me@example.com";
    var subject = "subject";
    var body = "A new quote has been requested, please process the attachment";
    // send a notification email with attached file or link to uploaded file 
    //gets the URL of the uploaded document 
    var docUrl = doc.getUrl();
    //adds the body text to the doc url to create the body message 
    var bodyUrl = body + "\n" +  docUrl;
    // gets the page I would like to post the announcement on
    var site = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("http://example.com/announcements-page");
    site.createAnnouncement("this is the title", '<a href="linkToGoogleDoc">LINK TEXT</a>');
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, bodyUrl);
    app.close();
    return app;
}
```

Could someone help me with getting the `"docUrl"` into the announcement? Thank you.

the `newAnnouncement(parameter)` function can be ignored, it's there in case it might help you help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this to work if you change this line:

```
site.createAnnouncement("this is the title", '<a href="linkToGoogleDoc">LINK TEXT</a>');
```

to this:

```
site.createAnnouncement("this is a title", '<a href="' + docUrl + '">LINK TEXT</a>');
```

Make sure that for each new announcement, you give the announcement a new title. For example, you can't use "this is a title" more than once. If you make these changes, and it still isn't working, try wrapping this line in a try/catch block and logging the exception to see what is going wrong.

```
try {
  site.createAnnouncement("this is a title", '<a href="' + docUrl + '">LINK TEXT</a>');
} catch (err) {
  Logger.log(err);
}
```